# Scanner with Delimiter as new line - java.util.InputMismatchException in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, java.util.scanner, eclipse-oxygen, inputmismatchexception

I have a small program to scan an Integer from console, also I would like to use new line character as delimiter.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class TestScanner {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\n");
    System.out.println("Enter the int");
    int testInt = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println(testInt);
}
```

}

Intellij runs and exist normal way..
[image]

Where as Eclipse produce, java.util.InputMismatchException

In Run mode you can observe an exception, with debug mode, code will run with out any issues
[image]

Source : jdk1.8.0_161 ( Oracle )

Eclipse : 
[image]

This is strange. Kindly help me to understand how this can be corrected. Thanking you!

Comment: On Windows, isn't the correct line delimiter "\r\n"?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Yes, System.lineseparator() will give the appropriate value. But using System.lineSeparator() fails with intellij..

Comment: Have you tried *not* setting it? The method is not for a *line* delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Late but... if you're in Windows you should use "\r\n" instead of just "\n"